# Разметка нестандартной таблицы html

Tags: html, css, table

помогите, пожалуйста сверстать подобную таблицу средствами html и сss. Буду крайне благодарен.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот форум помогает разобраться а не написать. Начните а мы поможем. Тут ничего сложного объединяйте строки через `rowspan` колонки через `conspan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разметка выглядит так, остальное дело стилей

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3">Текст</td>
   <td colspan="2">Текст</td>
   <td colspan="5">Текст</td>
   <td colspan="3">Текст</td>
   <td colspan="4">Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><span class="rotate">Текст</span></td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Текст</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Текст</td>
   <td rowspan="2">Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="19">Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
   <td>Текст</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```